# iOS NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 with ClientCertificate Validation challenge

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to implement https client certificate authentication in iOS with `NSURLSession`. Here is what I am doing:

```
-(void) httpPostWithCustomDelegate :(NSDictionary *) params
{
    NSString *ppyRequestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/fetchcountryCities", PPBaseURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ppyRequestURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       Log(@"ASDAD");
    }];
    [postDataTask resume]; 
}
```

I am providing the client certificate in challenge handler like this:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{

    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }

    else    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {
               NSURLCredential *credential = [self provideClientCertificate];
                completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
            }
}
```

Here is how I load my client certificate,

```
- (SecIdentityRef)findClientCertificate {
    SecIdentityRef clientCertificate = NULL;

    if (clientCertificate) {
        CFRelease(clientCertificate);
        clientCertificate = NULL;
    }

    NSString *pkcs12Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"johndoe" ofType:@"p12"];
    NSData *pkcs12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pkcs12Path];

    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)pkcs12Data;
    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };
    CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = NULL;

    OSStatus err = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, optionsDictionary, &items);

    CFRelease(optionsDictionary);
    CFRelease(password);

    if (err == errSecSuccess && CFArrayGetCount(items) > 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef pkcsDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);

        SecTrustRef trust = (SecTrustRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pkcsDict, kSecImportItemTrust);

        if (trust != NULL) {
            clientCertificate = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pkcsDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);
            CFRetain(clientCertificate);
        }
    }

    if (items) {
        CFRelease(items);
    }

    return clientCertificate;
}

- (NSURLCredential *)provideClientCertificate {
    SecIdentityRef identity = [self findClientCertificate];

    if (!identity) {
        return nil;
    }

    SecCertificateRef certificate = NULL;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate (identity, &certificate);
    const void *certs[] = {certificate};
    CFArrayRef certArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, certs, 1, NULL);
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity certificates:(__bridge NSArray *)certArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
    CFRelease(certArray);

    return credential;
}
```

Now when the API is called I am getting back this error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8428df4d40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}

I am getting the same error on simulator and device. I am completely stuck. Not sure what's going wrong here.

*****Update*****
I did check with Charles proxy to find out more details. To my surprise when I added the client certificate to charles proxy I am getting back response from server, so am I missing some settings in plist or issue with loading p12?

From plist settings,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>test.mydomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I see three problems:

- You're making a POST request without providing a request body.  This will probably cause the request to fail right off the bad without ever even going out to the server.
- Your server trust handling, as written, effectively removes any protection you would otherwise get from TLS by telling the OS to blindly trust it (I think).

  You should either A. tell NSURLSession to perform default handling in the server trust case or B. check the cert yourself and *then* tell it to use the cert.
- Your identity includes only the client certificate and not any intermediate certificates that may be required for the server to trust it.

  You should probably combine those two methods, using the first identity you find, but taking every certificate that you find in the identity file and adding them all to the certificates array (possibly along with the client certificate itself, but I vaguely recall that you aren't supposed to add it there; try it both ways and see which one fails).

Mind you, if you know that none of your users' identities will ever have a certificate chain, then that third one probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried all your suggestions but still getting back same error.

Comment: I did check with charles proxy to find out more details. To my surprise when I added the client certificate to charles proxy I am getting back response from server, so am I missing some settings in plist or issue with loading p12?

Comment: Wait... it works if you're going through a proxy, but otherwise it fails?

Comment: Yes, it works via proxy when I add client certificate to proxy. But my app fails to connect after the client challenge. I am getting back above mentioned message.

Comment: You mean you're having the proxy send the client cert to your server?  You shouldn't be doing that; all that tells us is that the client cert is valid.  The purpose for using Charles Proxy is to see what your app is actually sending to the proxy, to determine how that differs from (for example) Safari logging into the same server.  Once you have that info, it should be easy to figure out what is wrong or missing.

Comment: No idea, unless the proxy crashed or something.